# Expectation for Jointly Distributed Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I just had a doubt about calculating the expectation of joint random vaiables.

Suppose we have a bivariate table such that:
P(3,0) = a,
P(1,2) = b,
P(2,1) = c,
P(0,3) = d

for P(x,y).
So, when we calculate expectation of both x and y: would it be like: 1.2.b + 2.1.c
and (we didn't take 'a' and 'd' cause it has 0 in multiplication)

Is this how we calculate expectation of joint rv's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are finding the expectation of $XY$. See this link for formulas: [discrete probability formulas](https://www.milefoot.com/math/stat/rv-jointdiscrete.htm)

In this case,
$$E(X)=3a+1b+2c$$
$$E(Y)=2b+1c+3d$$